# Bitwise X-OR properties for competitive programming

Tags: xor

What are some equations/ inequalities and properties of bitwise X-OR that can be used in competitive programming.

Comment: I am not aware of remarkable properties of bitwise operations that would differ from the corresponding properties of logical operators applied... bitwise. These operations are often used for masking (selective reset, set or flip).

Comment: This is the highest level of arrogance that I have seen in a while. My daily rate is £500 per day. That's what you have to pay me to answer this question.

Comment: Where you are [quoting 3rd party content](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), make that clear in the text, one possibility being a *block quote* (supported by the post editor).

Comment: This site is populated by volunteers, who are here to contribute to the mission of the site.  People usually don't take well to demands.  Demands can  leave the impression that you think you can tell people what to do, and that might trigger strong reactions.  I think you might be more successful by asking a concrete question, one that will be relevant and useful to others in the future.

Comment: The question seems too broad and open-ended to me.  This site works best for narrowly focused technical questions that can be answered in a few paragraphs and that have a single answer.  We also consider it important that the question identify requirements that make it easy for others to judge answers.  Any community votes on whether to put this question on hold?

Comment: (What are you trying to get at with adding examples as comments? How would you use any in programming, *competitive*, at that?)

Comment: Please don't add clarifications in the comments.  We expect questions to be self-contained and to read well for someone who encounters them for the first time.  People shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you're asking.  We expect you to respond to feedback by [edit]ing your post to improve it.  A few examples are not a substitute for a clearly specified problem statement, with requirements or criteria for evaluating answers.

Comment: @D.W.: editing the questions *without notice* often makes the comments and/or early answers meaningless or weird. [I known that there is the edition history, but this is not convenient.]

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Edits to clarify the question are good.  Edits to change the question are usually a bad idea, particularly if the question was already answered.  But if the goal is to change the question, leaving that information in a comment usually isn't better anyway.

Comment: @D.W.: in this particular case, the OP did silently change the question in a significant way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Ahh, I see, good point!  I missed that.  Sorry for failing to grasp your point.  Thank you for explaining.  (In this case, possibly it's all for the best, as the original question was arguably too broad, and there were no answers yet?)

Answer (score 1):

*Exclusive or* is non-monotone, linear, symmetric, balanced, evasive.

Comment: The question is about *bitwise* operations.

Comment: Exclusive or is evasive. What does it mean?

Comment: [Evasive Boolean functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evasive_Boolean_function) have at least one branch in the decision tree needing all inputs. Which isn't to say much with just two inputs: The non-evasive ones are constant or depend on one input, only.

Comment: Out of AND, OR, NOT which one is non-evasive?

Comment: NOT does not take two inputs. There are 16 binary Boolean functions; I characterised the non-evasive ones [above](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152106/bitwise-x-or-properties-for-competitive-programming/152110?noredirect=1#comment319848_152110). (You can edit this post …)

Comment: @VaibhavVishalSingh: Where the $\oplus$ of $n$ inputs is false/0, an even number of them was true/1 - including 0/none. (Apropos of what?)